# Rest API, take request fields. handle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemailer

*I stood in a stupor. And I need help.*

**I do rest full api on express**


I want to do this if a request comes in `type: reset_password` -> I sent an email to reset my password.(it can be both registration and auth)

But I don't know how to pass it into a query. And that is, how to do it.
I trimmed the code.

```
const send = async (req, res) => {
    const key = req.query.apiKey;
    const type = req.query.type;
    const to = req.query.to;
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (rows.length == 0) {
            res.status(401).json({"apiKey":"error"})
              } else {
                  if (email.validate(to)) {
                        sendmail(type, to)
                      } else {
                        res.status(422)
                }
            }   
}
```

sendmail:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const ejs = require('ejs')
const path = require('path')

const sendmail = async (type, to, url) => {
  try {
    const reset_password = path.join(__dirname, "../template/resetpassword.ejs")
    const signup_auth = path.join(__dirname, "../template/signupauth.ejs")
    const sign_in_auth = path.join(__dirname, "../template/signinauth.ejs")
    const data = await ejs.renderFile(reset_password,signup_auth,sign_in_auth, { to, url } )

    let testAccount = await nodemailer.createTestAccount();

    // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: "smtp.ethereal.email",
      port: 587,
      secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
      auth: {
        user: testAccount.user, // generated ethereal user
        pass: testAccount.pass, // generated ethereal password
      },
    });
   
   const send = await transporter.sendMail({
      from: 'dev@test.io',
      to: to,
      text: "Hello world?",
      subject: "test",
      html: ??? 
  })

  console.log("Success send: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(send));

  }catch (err) {
    console.log('Error send: ' + err.message);
  }
}
module.exports = sendmail;
```

**Now I have a question. How do I send a request: reset_password,signup_auth,sign_in_auth**
That is, how do I pass it on to the type: reset_password,signup_auth,sign_in_auth

```
http://localhost:3000/api?apiKey=key&type=reset_password,signup_auth,sign_in_auth
```

How do I take it and process it?
I need to accept  type=auth signup reset to api rest
I'm sorry, maybe I didn't make my point correctly.

Comment: Wow I Am Super Confused Please Review Your Question An Be More Clear  PS I read it like 4 times now

Comment: Where did `err` and `rows` and `email` variables come from in the first snippet?

Comment: @Ogoh.cyril,
Yes. Indeed, I failed to make my point. What I want to do is this: `http://localhost:3000/api?apiKey=key&type=reset_password`,that would send a letter template reset_password, and similarly with others, do I make myself clear?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, I trimmed the script. These are database queries